# iPhone how to cancel stop performSelector

Tags: iphone

In my iPhone app, i'm using the following function to do something after some delay

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```

Is there any way to cancel this performSelector and stop doing some thing after the delay?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:yourTarget selector:aSelector object: anArgument];
```

Comment: Is there any option for swift?

Answer (score 2):

I thought it might be useful for people to see some actual code, so here are two that I use to stop sounds and swiping when I go to another screen.

```
- (void)handleSwipeNext {

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleSwipeNext) object:nil];

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(playPromptAndTarget) object:nil];

// do some swipe handling stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.0 version :

```
NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(yourFunc), object: nil)
```