# How to stop performing selector?

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector

Im trying to figure out how to stop performing a selector

I can start one by doing this

```
            [self performSelector:@selector(vibe)];
```

But im trying to figure out how i can stop one.

Any help would be very much appreciated..Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone how to cancel stop performSelector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649273/iphone-how-to-cancel-stop-performselector)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`performSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3a) method is equivalent to sending a selector message directly to the receiver, so it cannot be canceled.  I.e., these two lines have the same effect:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(vibe)];
[self vibe];
```

The [`cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget%3a) (and similar) methods can only cancel selector messages which are not performed immediately.  You can send such a message via the [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget%3aselector%3aobject%3a) (and similar) methods.

See Table 3-2 of the [Run Loop Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW19) section of Apple's Thread Programming Guide for more information.

Answer (score 7):

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
// or
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(vibe) object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not immediately obvious, but I believe the following should work:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```