# Perform method after delay and cancel it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to to perform method after 2.0 seconds, but i want to be able to cancel it if before the 5 seconds if another call made , but i noticed that the `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget` send object nil and performSelector send object `NSString`.

Can it make a problems?

```
-(void)startRecord:(NSString*)name {
    if (self.needToStartRecording) {
        //Cancel last call
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startRecordAfterDelay:) object:nil];
    }
    self.needToStartRecording = YES;

    [self performSelector:@selector(startRecordAfterDelay:) withObject:name afterDelay:5.0];
}

-(void)startRecordAfterDelay:(NSString*)name {
    self.needToStartRecording = NO;

    //Do My Stuff
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649273/iphone-how-to-cancel-stop-performselector

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation, if you pass `nil`, only a request performed with `nil` will be canceled. You should store somewhere the previous value.

> The argument for requests previously registered with the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: instance method. Argument equality is determined using isEqual:, so the value need not be the same object that was passed originally. Pass nil to match a request for nil that was originally passed as the argument.

Additionaly, if you have only this selector used with delay, you could call

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]
```

This will cancel all previous request sent to self

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually:

Add a `BOOL` value to your code with a default value of `NO`, and if another call made change its value to `YES`.

And in your `startRecordAfterDelay:(NSString*)name` method, check the value of the `BOOL`, if it was `NO`, proceed the action, `else` ignore the call.